# getting 401 to access http://localhost:8080/oauth/token

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, oauth, spring-boot

I am hitting one end point from my angularjs client app to login when I am doing that one I am getting the following ERROR in browser console

OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/oauth/token 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/oauth/token. Invalid HTTP status code 401

It's server side code to accept CORS from the client.

```html
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

 public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
  HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
  chain.doFilter(req, res);
 }

 public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

 public void destroy() {}

}
```

It's client side code which calling the http://localhost:8080/oauth/token

```html
angular.module('frontendApp')
  .factory('AuthServerProvider', function loginService($http, localStorageService, Base64, API_SERVER) {
    return {
      login: function (credentials) {
        var data = "username=" + credentials.username + "&password="
          + credentials.password + "&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&" +
          "client_secret=123456&client_id=clientapp";
        return $http.post(API_SERVER + 'oauth/token', data, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Authorization": "Basic " + Base64.encode("clientapp" + ':' + "123456")
          }
        }).success(function (response) {
          var expiredAt = new Date();
          expiredAt.setSeconds(expiredAt.getSeconds() + response.expires_in);
          response.expires_at = expiredAt.getTime();
          localStorageService.set('token', response);
          return response;
        });
      },
      logout: function () {
        // logout from the server
        $http.post('api/logout').then(function () {
          localStorageService.clearAll();
        });
      },
      getToken: function () {
        return localStorageService.get('token');
      },
      hasValidToken: function () {
        var token = this.getToken();
        return token && token.expires_at && token.expires_at > new Date().getTime();
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: You add the url oauth/auth to anonymous permission in Spring?

Comment: Add 'Authorization' header to the **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** list

Comment: @Michael I already added in the code these **Access-Control-Allow-Headers list** please see once, my credentials are not adding to request when i seen in browser console in the network.

Comment: The OPTION request was sent from the browser to check access permission - not from angular. Not sure about the solution, but you should google for `CORS with credentials `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of OPTIONS request, you should not do further processing, i.e. skip the call to `chain.doFilter(req, res)`, e.g.:

```
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type,access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
```

Comment: I added your code still the application is not working  still I am getting this following error in my browser console "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/oauth/token. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers"

Comment: The client should not send "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header, it is sent by the server to client! Remove it from your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

For Oauth2 you will be having this configuration class which extends `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`. In this class you can add this code

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public static class AuthServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
   

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
        

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.applyPermitDefaultValues();

       AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer 
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/oauth/token", config);
        CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter(source);
        security.addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(filter);
    }
}
```

This will add the configs of cors for Oauth